# vector usage segmentation fault

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I get segmentation fault on my code. It is a game that can be thought like x-o-x. A function that `playable_dots` checks dots whether it is playable. The other one is for turn of computer so computer movement. As far as I eliminate  I doubt both of them. I also check boundries but I'm sure there is no issue about boundries. Before conversion of vector i.e. const vector < vector > &board, vector < vector > &wriggles, it works well because they were arrays. `char board[MAX][MAX]`
and `bool wriggles[MAX][MAX]` For all code: http://bit.ly/1Phz76d

Playable moves:

```
// Precondition: p_size >= 4 and even, 2D char array, a specified char
//               2D bool array
// Postcondition: determine proper playable dots and return how many
//                playable dots there are, otherwise 0, stand for true
int playable_moves(const vector < vector<char> > &board, vector < vector<bool> > &wriggles,
                      char const player, int const p_size)
{
    bool go_on;
    int wriggles_count = 0;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < p_size ; ++i)
        for(int j = 0 ; j < p_size ; ++j)
            wriggles[i][j] = false;

    // search legal playable dots
    for(int i = 0 ; i < p_size ; ++i)
        for(int j = 0 ; j < p_size ; ++j)
        {
            if(board[i][j] != what_symbol)  // if not dot
                continue;                   // don't do rest of the code
            // increment the loop

            for(int ii = 1 ; ii > -2 ; --ii)
                for(int jj = 1 ; jj > -2 ; --jj)
                {

                    if(check_boundry_for_rival(i, j, ii, jj, p_size))
                        continue;

                    if(specify_rival(player) == board[i + ii][j + jj])
                    {
                        go_on = true;
                        int x_coor = i + ii;
                        int y_coor = j + jj;

                        while(go_on)
                        {
                            x_coor += ii;
                            y_coor += jj;

                            if(check_boundry_for_player(x_coor, y_coor, p_size)
                               || board[x_coor][y_coor] == what_symbol)
                                go_on = false;

                            else if(player == board[x_coor][y_coor])
                            {
                                wriggles_count += 1;
                                //if(p_symbol == player)
                                //    cout << i + 1 << static_cast<char>(j + 'a') << ", ";

                                wriggles[i][j] = true;
                                go_on = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    return wriggles_count;
}
```

computer moves:

```
// Precondition: p_size >= 4 and even, 2D char array, a specified char
//               2D bool array
// Postcondition: determine proper playable dots and return how many
//                playable dots there are, otherwise 0, stand for true
int computer_moves(const vector < vector<char> > &board, vector < vector<bool> > &wriggles,
                      char const player, int const p_size)
{
    bool go_on;
    int wriggles_count = 0;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < p_size ; ++i)
        for(int j = 0 ; j < p_size ; ++j)
            wriggles[i][j] = false;

    // search legal playable dots
    for(int i = 0 ; i < p_size ; ++i)
        for(int j = 0 ; j < p_size ; ++j)
        {
            if(board[i][j] != what_symbol)  // if not dot
                continue;                   // don't do rest of the code
            // increment the loop

            for(int ii = 1 ; ii > -2 ; --ii)
                for(int jj = 1 ; jj > -2 ; --jj)
                {

                    if(check_boundry_for_rival(i, j, ii, jj, p_size))
                        continue;

                    if(specify_rival(player) == board[i + ii][j + jj])
                    {
                        go_on = true;
                        int x_coor = i + ii;
                        int y_coor = j + jj;

                        while(go_on)
                        {
                            x_coor += ii;
                            y_coor += jj;

                            if(check_boundry_for_player(x_coor, y_coor, p_size)
                               || board[x_coor][y_coor] == what_symbol)
                                go_on = false;

                            else if(player == board[x_coor][y_coor])
                            {
                                wriggles_count += 1;
                                //if(p_symbol == player)
                                //    cout << i + 1 << static_cast<char>(j + 'a') << ", ";

                                wriggles[i][j] = true;
                                go_on = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    return wriggles_count;
}
```

For boundries:

```
bool check_boundry_for_rival(int const i,int const j,
                             int const around_r, int const around_c, int const p_size)
{
    return (i == 0 && around_r == -1) || i + around_r >= p_size || // outta up range
    (j == 0 && around_c == -1) || j + around_c >= p_size || // outta down range
    (around_r == 0 && around_c == 0);// if the coordinate itself

}

// Precondition:  p_size >= 4 and even, the others must be int int
// Postcondition: while the scanning with same coordinate outta boundry return false
bool check_boundry_for_player(int const i,int const j, int const p_size)
{
    return p_size + 1 < i || i < 0 || p_size + 1 < j || j < 0;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where (in *your* code) do you get the crash? Have you tried running in a debugger to catch the crash? What are the values of the involved variables?

Comment: turn of computer i get the crashing.  Any suitable values as coordinates like 2 a. I have added images thanks for your interest @JoachimPileborg

Comment: Good start with the edit, but you still don't show the code (the `playable_wriggles` function) where the crash happens, so it's still not possible to say anything. Please show it and mark out in the code which line the crash happens. And even from your images it's not possible to see all values, for example what is the size of the `wriggles` vector?

Comment: I've added all code as link in the post. Sir, I really can't find the exact crashing line, If I find I will of course try to fix it but I can't do anything at this situation. As an input just be entered number and letter then if the entered coors can be playable put the symbol then convert between putted symbols https://www.mathsisfun.com/games/reversi.html @JoachimPileborg

Comment: I don't know what IDE you're using, but try double-clicking on a function in the call stack, it usually works in most places to take you to the function *and* the line where it happened.

Comment: on xcode there is no option like your saying @JoachimPileborg

Comment: In your `check_boundry_for_player` function, you check if coordinates are greater than the `size + 1`. However, I would expect you to check for `size - 1`, as a vector with size `x` has valid ranges of `0 to x - 1`. This might be the root of your problem.